# Selenium via Node.js and webdriverIO: timeout without effect

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, webdriver-io

**testfile.js**

```
var webdriverio = require('webdriverio');
var options = {
    desiredCapabilities: {
        browserName: 'firefox'
    }
};

webdriverio
    .remote(options)
    .init()
    .url('http://localhost/proj/index.php')
    .moveToObject('div.media')             // Move to DIV
    .timeouts('implicit',6000)             // Wait...
    .saveScreenshot('./snapshot1.png')     // Take Screenshot
    .end();
```

`.timeouts` has no effect. The screenshot is taken almost instantly afer moveToObject, no matter which parameter I choose to call [`.timeouts(['scrip'|'implicit'|'page load'], ms).`](http://webdriver.io/api/protocol/timeouts.html) with.

I get also the same result with the callback function:

```
.timeouts('implicit',6000).then(function(){
    this.timeouts('implicit',6000)
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: May be you are looking for `pause` instead of `timeouts`? http://webdriver.io/api/utility/pause.html

Comment: That's what I was looking for. Thanks! :D Can you please write this as an answer so I can accept it as the right one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To delay queue execution use `pause` instead of `timeouts`

http://webdriver.io/api/utility/pause.html